Problems calling functions with web3 from python from polygon testnet
I was trying to call a function from my python server to a contract deployed on cardona testnet polygon zkevm.
This is my contract:
        require(bytes(filename).length > 0, "Filename cannot be empty");
        require(filehash != bytes32(0), "File hash cannot be zero");
        require(filesize > 0, "File size must be greater than zero");
        require(date > 0, "Date must be valid");
        fileMetadata[msg.sender].push(FileMetadata(filehash, filesize, date, filename));
        emit MetadataStored(msg.sender, fileMetadata[msg.sender].length - 1, filename, filehash, filesize, date);
    }


Here I try to call the method:
    nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_address)
    print(f"Nonce: {nonce}")

    # Prepare data for the transaction
    file_hash_bytes = Web3.toBytes(hexstr=metadata['filehash'])  # Convert bytes32 to proper format
    
    current_time = int(time.time())
    
    # Encode function call
    tx_data = contract.functions.storeMetadata(
        metadata['filename'],
        file_hash_bytes,
        metadata['size'],
        current_time
    ).buildTransaction({
        'chainId': 2442,  
        'gas': 1000000,  
        'gasPrice': w3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),  
        'nonce': nonce,
    })

    # Sign and send the transaction
    signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx_data, private_key=private_key)
    tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    
    print(f"Transaction hash: {tx_hash.hex()}")


But I can't call the function. ¿Anybody know how can I call this method?
I'm getting following errors:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py in _handle_msg(self, msg)
    754                 if 'buffer_paths' in data:
    755                     _put_buffers(state, data['buffer_paths'], msg['buffers'])
--> 756                 self.set_state(state)
    757 
    758         # Handle a state request.

14 frames
<ipython-input-31-9a3f4855d4d8> in store_metadata(metadata)
    306         metadata['size'],
    307         current_time
--> 308     ).buildTransaction({
    309         'chainId': 2442,
    310         'gas': 1000000,

AttributeError: 'storeMetadata' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction'


Thanks very much.

It should be build_transaction instead of buildTransaction.
So, replace:
# Encode function call
tx_data = contract.functions.storeMetadata(
    metadata['filename'],
    file_hash_bytes,
    metadata['size'],
    current_time
).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': 2442,  
    'gas': 1000000,  
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),  
    'nonce': nonce,
})

with:
# Encode function call
tx_data = contract.functions.storeMetadata(
    metadata['filename'],
    file_hash_bytes,
    metadata['size'],
    current_time
).build_transaction({
    'chainId': 2442,  
    'gas': 1000000,  
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),  
    'nonce': nonce,
})

